# Error in Converting String type to Object

Tags: python

This the problem I am facing with the following code

```
class Dot:

    def __init__(self, connections, name):
        self.name = name
        self.connections = connections
        self.availalbe = True
        return


def create_dot(i):
    for n in range(i):
        name = "dot" + str(n)
        globals()[name] = Dot(0, name)
        print("Created " + name)


def join_dot(a,b):
    if a.connections == 3:
        print(a.name + " is unavailable ")
        a.available = False
    elif b.connections == 3:
        print(a.name + " is unavailable ")
        b.available = False
    else:
        a.connections += 1
        b.connections += 1
        print("dots joined")
        create_dot(2)
        if a.connections == 3:
            print(a.name + " is unavailable ")
            a.available = False
        elif b.connections == 3:
            print(a.name + " is unavailable ")
            b.available = False



dotcount = int(input("Initial Dots: "))
create_dot(dotcount)
while True:
    a = input("Enter Dot Name: ")
    b = input("Enter Dot Name: ")
    join_dot(a,b)
```

This is the error that it outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PatrickSilveira/OneDrive - mail.ccsf.edu/Google Drive/Programming/sprouts.py", line 43, in <module>
    join_dot(a,b)
  File "C:/Users/PatrickSilveira/OneDrive - mail.ccsf.edu/Google Drive/Programming/sprouts.py", line 18, in join_dot
    if a.connections == 3:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'connections'
```

I believe that its somewhat related to str and the "instance" type.
How can I solve this issue?
Python 3.7
............................................................

Comment: Please post [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) next time. Your code could be a few lines long in the present case. Posting minimal example makes it much easier to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I see what you mean. You probably expected `input()` to act like in python 2, where it was equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`. But in python 3, the `input` function is what was `raw_input` in python2, so the most staight-forward way is to do `a = eval(input("Enter dot name: "))`. This is severely vulnerable, however, since anyone can execute any code there. A slightly better (although also quite wrong) way is to do `a = globals()[input("Enter dot name: ")]`. I guess this is the cheaty workaround you're looking for. (Obviously, this should be applied to "`b =`" as well)

Comment: Thanks! But what do you mean by "Vulnerable"?

Comment: Well, it doesn't really affect the app you use only yourself, but if, for instance, it was exposed through a web interface or set up as a suid linux binary, one could give "`exec('import os\nos.system(\'rm -rf /\')')`", which would delete your entire system (or, in a similar way, do anything else they'd like to.

Answer (score 0):

Your `a` of `str` type, not an instance of `Dot`. Hence there is no reason why `a` would have `connections` property.

Comment: Is there some workaround such that I could achieve the same thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "the same thing"?

Comment: I want "a" and "b" to be recognized as objects instead of just variables..

Comment: it looks like you are lacking the concepts of oops here.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a and b as objects of the class Dot and then you pass the name of the dot and the connections attributes as parameters to the class